# Local Adminstrator groups in Powershell from remote system

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to retrieve the list of Administrators from a system. Below is the script that I am using currently to retrieve from the local system.

```
Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators
```

This retrieves the result as expected. Now to retrieve the same result from a remote system, I explored `invoke-command` option and its able to connect to the remote system. The issue is I am unable to retrieve the details from older system which has powershell version older than 5.1 since `Get-LocalGroupMember` cmdlet is available only from 5.1. Kindly help to get the local administrator group details from a remote system which has PS version older than 5.1

Below is my current script.

```
 $AdminAccountName=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators| where {$_.name -eq 'Domain\accountName'}|Select name}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Powershell versions before 5.1 - you need to use net.exe command:

```
net localgroup Administrators
```

It will need some parsing, but the command is there.

This also works with Invoke-Command:

```
Invoke-Command ComputerName -ScriptBlock { net localgroup administrators }
```